# Check if a variable is undef in puppet template

Tags: erb, puppet

What is the proper way to check if a variable is undef in a puppet template?

In the manifest the variable is defined as follows

```
$myvar = undef
```

How is this checked in the template?

Is saw the following two variants

```
<% if @myvar -%>
<% end -%>
```

and

```
<% if not @myvar.nil? and @myvar -%>
<% end -%>
```

They both seem to work in my case, but I wonder if the first approach fails in on certain cases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Puppet documentation (at the time of writing this answer) explains it very well: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_template_erb.html#concept-5365

Since `undef` is not the same as `false`, just using an `if` is not a good way to check for it. Also when a variable is defined, but has a value of `false` or `nil` it is also impossible to check with a simple `if`.

This is why you want to use `scope.lookupvar(‘variable’)` and check its return value for `:undef` or `:undefined` (or `nil`) to know if it was set to `undef`, or never set at all.

Comment: The puppetlabs page was moved to https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html#testing-for-undefined-variables

Comment: How about checking, whether a _resource_ is defined? In a Puppet manifest I'd do `if (defined(File['/home/foo']))` -- what about erb-templates?

Comment: Welcome to URL persistence. We're now in 2019 and guess what? The URL has changed again :) https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/lang_template_erb.html#concept-5365 It now says: `Note: If a Puppet variable was never defined, its value is undef, which means its value in a template is nil.`

Answer (score 8):

I'd say the check depends on whether you want an alternative when the variable is not defined.

I'm using the following rules:

## Required variable

Check in your puppet script whether the variable contains the expected value before even considering template rendering:

```
if $myvar == undef {
    fail {"You really must set myvar, seriously."}
}

if ! $anothervar {
    fail {"anothervar is false, undefined or empty."}
}
```

You can make your life easier by setting the type of parameters explicitly. This spares you type comparisons and conversions.

In your template you simply write the variables then:

```
<%= @myvar %>
<%= @anothervar %>
```

## Optional variable that must be defined

If you assume the variable is defined, you can treat it as boolean.

The mapping is as follows ([source](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/puppet-users/147by1key3/checking-a-variable-is-not-undef#20140713grem6zqsai7qjbgkmd2f4ia3qi)):

- *falsey*: empty string, false, undef
- *truthy*: everything else

In Puppet >=4:

- *falsey*: false, undef
- *truthy*: everything else

**Examples:**

print 'something' if @myvar evaluates to true, otherwise 'something else'.

```
<% if @myvar %>something<% else %>something else<% end %>
```

print 'something' if @myvar evaluates to true

```
<% if @myvar %>something<% end %>
```

print @myvar if it evaluates to true, otherwise 'alternative' %>

```
<%= @myvar ? @myvar : 'alternative'  %>
```

## Optional variable that may be defined

If you are not sure a variable is even defined and don't want to make wrong assumptions, check it in the template.

**Examples:**

print 'something' followed by @myvar if @myvar is defined and not empty

```
<% if defined?(@myvar) && ! @myvar.empty? %>something<%= @myvar %><% end %>
```

print @myvar if it's defined and greater than 10

```
<%= @myvar if defined?(@myvar) && @myvar > 10 %>
```

Comment: Syntax error here. `fail()` is a function, you must use parentheses `()` not curly braces `{}`

Answer (score 2):

The first one should work like a charm, it's what is being taught in the courses as well.

Number two seems... redundant.

Comment: When the value of `@myvar` is `false`, it is not the same as when it is `undef`. Thus the first variant will ignore values of `false`, not what the subj. is asking for.